# Arquillian test with custom jre (using Maven dependency)

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian

I have a project which use a specific JRE : that contains some additionnal lib and custo java.security entries... and i want to run test in other machine which i don't have access to update JRE with my specific configuration.

What I want to do :

1. get JRE distribution and put it in target folder : using Maven dependency
2. with Maven plugin : update this JRE with my specific configuration
3. set $JAVA_HOME with my custom JRE in target using arquillian.xml configuration file

It is possible to do that with Arquillian ?

Have you any other suggestion ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For the first both steps you can use the Maven dependency plugin.

For the integration test you can use the failsafe plugin, there is a parameter called [jvm](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#jvm). There is no need to override the jvm with the *arquillian.xml*.

> Option to specify the jvm (or path to the java executable) to use with the forking options. For the default, the jvm will be a new instance of the same VM as the one used to run Maven. JVM settings are not inherited from MAVEN_OPTS.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvm>path to jvm or java executable</jvm>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```